# How to retrieve worker logs for a Dask-YARN job?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a simple Dask-YARN script that does only one task: load a file from HDFS, as shown below. However, I'm running into a bug in the code, so I added a `print` statement in the function, but I don't see that statement being executed in the worker logs which I obtain using `yarn logs -applicationId {application_id}`. I even tried the method `Client.get_worker_logs()`, however that doesn't display the `stdout` as well, just shows some `INFO` about the worker(s). How does one obtain worker logs after the execution of the code has completed?

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import json

import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster


@dask.delayed
def load(input_file):
    print("In call of Load...")
    with open(input_file, "r") as fo:
        data = json.load(fo)
    return data


# Process input args
(_, filename) = sys.argv


dag_1 = {
    'load-1': (load, filename)
}

print("Building tasks...")
tasks = dask.get(dag_1, 'load-1')

print("Creating YARN cluster now...")
cluster = YarnCluster()
print("Scaling YARN cluster now...")
cluster.scale(1)
print("Creating Client now...")
client = Client(cluster)

print("Getting logs..1")
print(client.get_worker_logs())

print("Doing Dask computations now...")
dask.compute(tasks)

print("Getting logs..2")
print(client.get_worker_logs())

print("Shutting down cluster now...")
cluster.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on here, print statements should (and usually do) end up in the log files stored by yarn.

If you want your debug statements to appear in the worker logs from `get_worker_logs`, you can use the worker logger directly:

```
from distributed.worker import logger
logger.info("This will show up in the worker logs")
```

Comment: Thanks @jiminy_crist! One could also use Python's own logging module. Is there any difference?

Comment: `get_worker_logs` only will grab the logs written using `distributed.worker.logger`, so you'd have to be writing to the same logger to make that work.

Comment: is there any way to configure this logger? Level, format, handlers, etc? I tried using both keys `logging` and `logging-file-config` in both the Dask config files: `~/config/dask/distributed.yaml` and `~/config/dask/yarn.yaml`, but they didn't have any effect?

Comment: The local configuration isn't used for the workers, you'd need to bundle the configuration with your environment, or ensure it exists on every node. If you're packaging an environment (e.g. using conda-pack), you can create a file at `yourenvironment/etc/dask/dask.yaml` to put the configuration in, and then distribute it as part of the environment tarball. Dask's configuration system reads all yaml files in a few different directories, so that name of the file isn't important, just the location. See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html for more info.

Comment: Also note it's  `~/.config/dask/...` not `~/config/dask/...` as you've typed above.

Comment: - I'm packaging my conda environment using `conda-pack`. Do you mean the file: `/path/to/conda_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/desitributed/distributed.yaml`? I cannot find `yourenvironment/etc/dask/dask.yaml`. If so, it doesn't seem like a good idea to edit python package file in your environment.

Comment: - Anyway, I edited the file by uncommenting `logging: -> distributed: info`, and changing the format by editing `admin: -> log-format: %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(level)s - %(message)s`, but not only this didn't have any effect, but even the distributed.worker.logger log does not appear in the worker logs anymore. 
(Btw, I have created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633097/how-to-capture-logs-from-workers-from-a-dask-yarn-job that may help clear things).

Comment: No, you'd *add* the file (and any missing directories) to your environment path before packaging. For example: `/path/to/conda_env/etc/dask/distributed.yaml`, you'd likely need to add the `etc` directory and everything after.